# Returning substring-after using FILTERXML

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a now deleted question, the OP asked to return `1.3` and `0.4` from `1^1.3%2^0.4`.

I immediately thought FILTERXML.

I was able to do it with:

```
=MID(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),FIND("^",FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))+1,99)
```

But that seemed too repetative.

I found `substring-after` in XPATH 1.0, but cannot get it to do what I want.  I first tried:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[substring-after(., '^')]")
```

But that returned both full strings and :

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","substring-after(//b, '^')")
```

Just returned an error.

Is there a way to use only FILTERXML to return the desired numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately `FILTERXML` cannot actually rework values and return them. Use it for filtering and returning those values of interest, but the reworking needs to be done outside. I have recently tried something similar and hit this anoying limitations of `XPATH` in Excel too. So a double substitute and returning values per position or containing a dot seems plausible

Comment: @JvdV - oh I knew you would jump on this one haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `XPATH` in Excel cannot seem to return reworked values, instead use `FILTERXML` for filtering and returning those nodes of interest. Reworking those nodes need to be done outside the function.

If you are intested in a single `FILTERXML` usage, I'd suggest a double `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"^","^%"),"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[contains(preceding::*[1],'^')]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"^","^%"),"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[.*0=0]")
```

Might you be interested in filtering through `FILTERXML`. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) would interest you?

Comment: Good idea, I like that.  also: `=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"^","^%"),"%","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[contains(.,'^')]/following-sibling::*[1]")` works.

Comment: And I already had the link bookmarked.  I got anchored on the `substring-after`.  I like the logic.

Comment: It's one of those XPATH functions I haven't yet included. Will do an update on that =) @ScottCraner.